# Why is the error *FileNotFound* shown to me?

Tags: python

Why is the error *FileNotFound* shown to me?

```
t=open("files1.txt")
x=t.read()
print(x)
t.close()
```

files1.txt looks something like this:

```
Hello
This is abc
This is third line
This is fourth
And so on...
Goodbye!
```

Both the files are in same folder still showing me the error that `files1.txt` not found.

Comment: Try: `import os` and `os.getcwd()`. Check if the output for the second one is the directory where you saved the files.

Comment: Your filename doesn't have a path, so Python looks for it in what it thinks is the current working directory. This is usually not what novices expect. So supply a path.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options to figure this.

1. Simulate error:

```
import os

try:
    os.remove('C:/workspace/python/data.txt')
    print('The file is removed.')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('The file is not present.')
```

2. Check if provided path has the file

```
import os

if os.path.isfile('C:/workspace/python/data.txt'):
    print('The file is present.')
else:
    print('The file is not present.')
```

if something is wrong with your file, you'll get "The file is not present"

3. Give the full path in your input

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not working on the right directory, I suggest you take a look at os module and learn it,
try this code and see:

```
import os
current_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(current_dir)
#do stuff
```